# Change image and quote on a click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a quick little page. I'm just learning JavaScript and it's taking some getting used to. I was able to create a page that changes quotes when the image is clicked. Now, I want the image to change with the quotes. So it will be: click on image 1, and image 2 will appear with quote 2. Click on image 2, and image 3 will appear with quote 3.

This is a pretty simple task but I have not been able to find an easy solution. I've spent a couple hours on this, which is sort of depressing.

Here's the page: https://aprilehrlich.github.io/dataint/

Following is what I've got in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ida B. Wells</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="MainProductImage"" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pUMKFP4p2Lo/maxresdefault.jpg" width="500px"" id="myImg">
<h1>“Quote 1.”</h1>
<p>- Ida B. Wells</p>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var quote1 = "“Quote 1.”";
var quote2 = "“Quote 2”";
var quote3 = "“Quote 3”";
var quote4 = "“Quote 4”";
var quote5 = "“Quote 5”";
var quote6 = "“Quote 6”";
var quote7 = "“Quote 7”";
var quote8 = "“Quote 8”";
var quote9 = "“Quote 9”";
var quote10 = "“Quote 10”";
$("img").click(function() {
    var currentQuote =  $("h1").text();
    $("h1").fadeOut(0); 
    if (currentQuote == quote1) {
        $("h1").text(quote2);
    }
    if (currentQuote == quote2) {
        $("h1").text(quote3);
    } 
    if (currentQuote == quote3) {
        $("h1").text(quote4);
    } 
    if (currentQuote == quote4) {
        $("h1").text(quote5);
    } 
    if (currentQuote == quote5) {
        $("h1").text(quote6);
    } 
    if (currentQuote == quote6) {
        $("h1").text(quote7);
    } 
    if (currentQuote == quote7) {
        $("h1").text(quote8);
    } 
    if (currentQuote == quote8) {
        $("h1").text(quote9);
    } 
    if (currentQuote == quote9) {
        $("h1").text(quote10);
    } 
    $("h1").fadeIn(1000);
});
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `attr` (attribute) function to change the `src` element. Here's an example. I made your code a little bit more dynamic so you can set as many quotes as you wish without changing your code:

HTML:

```
<img id="MainProductImage" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/2a/b4/e7/2ab4e74ad637f9c8ecb792b8b7d605a6.jpg" id="myImg" data-current-quote="0">
<h1>“Quote 1.”</h1>
<p>- Ida B. Wells</p>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Quotes/Image Array
  var quotes = [
      { quote: "Quote1", img: "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/2a/b4/e7/2ab4e74ad637f9c8ecb792b8b7d605a6.jpg"},
      { quote: "Quote2", img: "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/af/52/03/af5203d09a0be9c9e655786c88c1d8b7.jpg"},
      { quote: "Quote3", img: "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/04/37/3c/04373c4f98797b202d13b9882e137690.jpg"}
  ];

  $("img").click(function(){

      var img = $("#MainProductImage"),
          //We look for the next quote, if it's the last we go to the beginning
          currentQuote = img.data("current-quote") === quotes.length -1 ? 0 : img.data("current-quote") + 1,
          nextQuote = quotes[currentQuote];

      //Set the current quote index in a data attribute
      img.data("current-quote", currentQuote);
      $("h1").fadeOut(0); 
      //Change the text
      $("h1").text(nextQuote.quote);
      //Change the image
      img.attr("src", nextQuote.img);
  });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p2bus29y/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
    {
        "CategoryID": 1,
        "CategoryName": "Soler Power Plant",
        "CategoryProducts": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "Name": 'Commercial Solar Power Plant',
            "SubTitle": 'Eco, Eco Friendly, Energy, Green, Solar',
            "Brand": 'ACS',
            "Usage": '',
            "Type": '',
            "Price": 'Rs 5 Lakh / Unit',
            "Body_Material": '',
            "Description": 'Having a pre-determined quality administration system, we are thoroughly involved in delivering Commercial Solar Power Plant.',
            "ImageUrl": 'assets/images/Products/Sola-power-plant.jpg',
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "Name": 'Industrial Solar Power Plants',
            "SubTitle": 'Eco Friendly, Save Energy',
            "Brand": 'ACS',
            "Usage": '',
            "Type": '',
            "Price": 'Rs 5 Lakh / Unit',
            "Body_Material": '',
            "Description": 'So as to become a preferential business name, we are thoroughly engrossed in shipping an inclusive collection of Industrial Solar Power Plants.',
            "ImageUrl": 'assets/images/Products/Industrial_Solar_Power_Plants.jpg',
        },
         {
             "ID": 3,
             "Name": 'On Grid Solar Plant',
             "SubTitle": 'Eco Friendly, Save Energy',
             "Brand": 'ACS',
             "Usage": '',
             "Type": '',
             "Price": 'Rs 1.1 Lakh / Unit',
             "Body_Material": '',
             "Description": "We are the leading firm of On Grid Solar Plant. To sustain the quality, our products are made under the guidance of industry certified professionals.",
             "ImageUrl": 'assets/images/Products/On_Grid_Solar_Plant.jpg',
         },
          {
              "ID": 4,
              "Name": 'On Grid Solar Power Plant',
              "SubTitle": 'Eco Friendly, Save Energy',
              "Brand": 'ACS',
              "Usage": '',
              "Type": '',
              "Price": 'Rs 5 Lakh / Unit',
              "Body_Material": '',
              "Description": "We are the leading firm of On Grid Solar Power Plant. To sustain the quality, our products are made under the guidance of industry top professionals.",
              "ImageUrl": 'assets/images/Products/On_Grid_Solar_Power_Plant.jpg',
          },
          {
              "ID": 5,
              "Name": 'Solar Power Plant',
              "SubTitle": 'Eco Friendly, Save Energy',
              "Brand": 'ACS',
              "Usage": '',
              "Type": '',
              "Price": 'Rs 5 Lakh / Unit',
              "Body_Material": '',
              "Description": "We are the leading firm of Solar Power Plant. To sustain the quality, our products are made under the guidance of industry certified professionals.",
              "ImageUrl": 'assets/images/Products/Solar_Power_Plant.jpg',
          },
        ]
    }
]




 function GetProducts() {

            var products = data;

            $.each(products, function () {

                //var product = products.filter(filterByID)
                var product = this;
                $('#ProductDetails').append('<h2 class="text-center">' + this.CategoryName + '</h2>');
                var details = product;
                $.each(details.CategoryProducts, function () {


                    tempData = tempData + '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">' +
                                    '<div class="project-box">' +
                                        '<div class="frame-outer">' +
                                            '<div class="frame">' +
                                                '<img style="width:350px;" src="' + this.ImageUrl + '" class="attachment-340x220 size-340x220 wp-post-image" alt="">' +
                                            '</div>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                        '<div class="text-box">' +
                                            '<h3><a>' + this.Name + '</a></h3>' +
                                            '<div class="tags-row">' +
                                                '<a class="link">' + this.SubTitle + '</a>' +
                                            '</div>' +
                                            '<p>' + this.Description + '</p>' +
                                            //'<a href="javascript:ViewMore(' + this.ID + ')" class="btn-readmore">More Details</a>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>';
                });

                $('#ProductDetails').append('<div class="row">' + tempData + '</div>');
                tempData = '';

            });
        }
```

Here, it's my own code may be it helps you. It does not belong to your code but you can understand and maybe you need to do like this

Answer (score 0):

I have created an array with the quote and image sources. I have incremented a counter to define the index of the array. I have also made it so the quote fades back in once everything is done, so the text doesn't change until it has faded out.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // set array of quotes and images
  var content = [
    ["“Quote 1.”", "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pUMKFP4p2Lo/maxresdefault.jpg"],
    ["“Quote 2.”", "http://www.stevensegallery.com/460/300"],
    ["“Quote 3.”", "http://www.stevensegallery.com/300/200"],
    ["“Quote 4.”", "http://www.stevensegallery.com/460/300"],
    ["“Quote 5.”", "http://www.stevensegallery.com/300/200"],
    ["“Quote 6.”", "http://www.stevensegallery.com/284/196"],
    ["“Quote 7.”", "http://www.stevensegallery.com/300/200"],
    ["“Quote 8.”", "http://www.stevensegallery.com/460/300"],
    ["“Quote 9.”", "http://www.stevensegallery.com/300/200"],
    ["“Quote 10.”", "http://www.stevensegallery.com/284/196"],
  ];
  // set counter to 1
  var count = 1;
  $("img").click(function(){
    // check is end of array reached and start from beginning
    count == content.length ? count = 0 : "";
    // fade h1 out
    $("h1").fadeOut(500, function() {
      // use counter to get the correct index of array to change the h1 to the relevent quote
      $("h1").text(content[count][0]);
      // use counter to get the correct index of array to change the h1 to the relevent image source
      $("img").attr("src", content[count][1]);
      // fade h1 back in after everything else is done
      $("h1").fadeIn(500);
      // increment count by 1
      count++;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<img id="MainProductImage"" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pUMKFP4p2Lo/maxresdefault.jpg" width="500px"" id="myImg">
<h1>“Quote 1.”</h1>
<p>- Ida B. Wells</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```